# Cannot resolve symbol ++ in Scala

Tags: scala, set, union

I want to return the union of two sets in the following way:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = s ++ t
```

I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol ++". What happened?

Comment: do you understand that your code has some other problems too ?

Comment: I do not know why I get this error with ++ symbol

Comment: What's `Set`? Is it `scala.collection.Set`?

Comment: type Set = Int => Boolean

Comment: Is this from Odersky's Coursera course?

Comment: That answers my question. I'd (re)watch all course up to this point.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on this seccion.

Comment: You're meant to implement a `union` with that definition of `Set`,  not just use a similar sounding one from the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type Set = Int => Boolean` defines `Set` to mean a function from `Int` to `Boolean`. There is no `++` method on functions. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type parameter of `Set` if you are using Scala Set:

```
def union(s:Set[Int], t:Set[Int]):Set[Int] = s ++ t
```